# How to add an intent to launch an app for printing any document

Tags: android

I have to develop an andriod app which will be used for printing. So, whenever a user opens any document/image and clicks on print option, my app has to be invoked. 
Have started working on andriod only a week back, can someone please guide me how to add an intent to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.